# simple_form association input switches from drop-down/select to text input upon failed validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, simple-form

I have a simple_form ui that works alright, I'm using `f.input :group_ids` to assign a Poll to a Group (Poll `has_and_belongs_to_many` :groups, but we're limiting it to just one in the UI).

I'd like a more elegant way to do the UI anyways, but it also causes serious problems when validation fails -- the input reverts to a text input with value: [4], where 4 is the id of the current group. (Beyond looking bad, this fails on submission unless the brackets are deleted manually)

```
<%= simple_form_for @poll do |f| %>
   <% if params[:group] %>
      <%= f.input :group_ids, :label => "Group", :selected => params[:group], :collection => @groups, :include_blank => false, :input_html => {:multiple => false} %>
   <% else %>
      <%= f.input :group_ids, :label => "Group", :collection => @groups, :include_blank => false, :input_html => {:multiple => false} %>
   <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

I'd love a better way to do this -- tried using f.association, but couldn't figure out how to limit it to a single-select dropdown.

Comment: Was hoping there'd be a way to do this in simple_form, but for now I'll just use a f.select https://github.com/codeforamerica/textizen/commit/9a3e46b4a1b13b6b4ce39d0a4d1471d4c23a5044

Comment: Turns out this was solved by the other part of the commit -- passing in the @groups variable to update and create instead of just new and edit. Reverted back to simple_form and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set **@groups** in methods **create** or **update** before render action **new** or **edit** respectively

For example

```
def new
  @groups = Group.all
  ....
end

def create
  @poll = Poll.new(poll_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @poll.save
      format.html { redirect_to ... }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @poll }
    else
      ### ! in case of validation is failed init data for the form ! ###
      @groups = Group.all
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: ... }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try and use collection_select:

e.g. somethings like f.collection_select(:group, :group_id, Group.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Group')

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select